# excel drop-down data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using list feature to implement drop-down in excel.

```
Sheet2!$A$2:$A$101
```

Is there a way to replace it with something like

```
Sheet2!$A$2:TILL_THE_END_UNTIL IT SEES A BLANK ROW
```

instead of hard-coding the last row number.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of both COUNTA and INDIRECT formulae:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&OFFSET($A$2,1,0,COUNTA(A:A),1))
```

If you had data in cells A2:A5, 5 is your max row. The indirection evaluates to B5. So the formula above will return the value of cell B5.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you mentioning two columns A and B, when I'm supposed to be concerned with only one column. Is that a typo?

Comment: If cell is blank then you will get wrong output of dropdown. Just verify it. (Lets take an example: First 4 cells has value and next 3 cells are blank then next cell has value? See what happens)

Answer (score 1):

I think Tiksi was heading towards using this as a range:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1)
```

The COUNTA will essentially return the final row in the sheet, and the offset will set up a range from A2:last-row.

You can add make this a named range to to simplify other formulae.

Comment: If cell is blank then you will get wrong output of dropdown. Just verify it. (Lets take an example: First 4 cells has value and next 3 cells are blank then next cell has value? See what happens)